# Laravel Horizon inactive and still processing

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, horizon

I run my Application on Kubernetes.
I have one Service for requests and one service for the worker processes.
If I access the Horizon UI it often shows the Inactive Status, but there are still jobs being processed by the worker. I know this because the JOBS PAST HOUR are getting more.

If I scale up my worker service there will be constantly "failing" Jobs with this exception Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException.
If I connect directly to the pods and run ps aux I will see that there are horizon instances running.

If I connect to a pod on which the worker is running and execute the horizon:list command it tells me that one (or multiple) Masters are running.

How can I further debug this?

Laravel version: 5.7.15

Horizon version: 2.0.0

Redis version: 3.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the Server Time was out of Sync so the "old" ones got restartet all the time